# In android, how to backup content of a java class and restore it

Tags: java, android

In my application has a java class which handle data for application.  I want to save content of that class and make data modifications and restore it later.  I was noticed by a problem that when i make change in original data the saved copy also changes.  How can i avoid it.  The code shown below is illustrative

```
public class HomeData {
   public int n;

   HomeData(){
      n = 10;
   }
}


HomeData homedata;
homedata.n = 15;

HomeData saveData = homedata;

// making changes
homedata.n = 50;


homedata = SaveData;

// i want the value of 'n' in homedata as 15
```

thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried cloning? it seems to be a problem of deep copy / shallow copy.

Comment: i can't understand, i am a newbie to java/android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both instances of `HomeData` (`saveData` and `g.OriginalData`) are only references to a memory address. When you copy saveData = g.OriginalData; you are actually copying the memory address. An Object (like `HomeData) behaves different than a simple`primitive`(like an int or a byte), you have to use methods to access their values.

In order to make some sort of *deepCopy*  you should override the method `clone()` in `HomeData`, where you make sure that **every** single variable and value contained in `HomeData` will be copied.

Like this:

```
public class HomeData implements Cloneable{

  public Object clone(){
      HomeData copy= new HomeData();
      copy.setValue(this.getValue());
      copy.setSomething(this.getSomething());

      //... and so on
      return copy;
   }

   ....
 }
```

Comment: You didn't wrote that HomeData should implement cloneable `HomeData implements Cloneable`.

Comment: My homedata is large class which contains variables and function.  Is i need to copy all these things to work proper.  Is any easy method is available  ?

Comment: you only have to copy the global variables of homedata. But yes, you have to if you want a real *copy* of your `Object`. Well there are other ways if you are looking for a *one time quick and dirty* solution (like `Serialization`, where you save the content of the Homedata in serialized form and then deserialize it when you need it again) but overriding the method `clone()` is the standard way to implement this.

Comment: After writing the above code (i.e. overriding clone() method), all you need to write is HomeData saveData = homedata.clone();

Answer (score 1):

```
HomeData homedata;
homedata.n = 15;
HomeData saveData = homedata; // 15 in saveData
// making changes
homedata.n = 50; // saveData will have 50 too

homedata = SaveData;// override the reference...
```

The problem it is you have only 1 memory allocation at the first line, and 2x reference to it.

Suggestion: -make a copy constructor:

```
HomeData(HomeData src){
 this.n = src.n;
}
```

Usage:

HomeData saveData = new Homedata(homedata);

Other solution is the clone as described in the other answer;

Comment: My homedata is large class which contains variables and function. Is i need to copy all these things to work proper. Is any easy method is available ?

Comment: you need to make a deep clone, a copy of the (primitive) fields, and deep clone of references